# How to work with variable/dynamic paths in JSONata?

Tags: jsonata

Consider the source JSON below

```
{
  "Player1": "Ryan",
  "Player2": "Nathan",
  "score": [
    {
      "match1": {
        "Ryan|Nathan": [
          {
            "Round1": {
              "total": 500
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

From here if I need to get the value of total, the JSONata query will look like:

```
{
    "Score": score.match1.`Ryan|Nathan`[0].Round1.total
}
```

and the result will be:

```
{
  "Score": 500
}
```

How do I modify the path in the query based on the values in the source, like if instead of Ryan and Nathan, the values for **Player1** and **Player2** were Will and Max respectively, and based on that it was **Will|Max**, how can I have my query change accordingly?

I tried to first dynamically create a string for the required path but I fail to understand how can I use this string as a path later on.

```
"score.match1.`" & Player1 & "|" & Player2 & "`[0].Round1.total"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [$lookup function](https://docs.jsonata.org/object-functions#lookup) to get value by a dynamically defined key:

```
{ 
  "Score": $lookup(score.match1, Player1 & "|" & Player2)[0].Round1.total 
}
```

Check it on the live playground: https://stedi.link/ffGrafH